# How to reset or remove mouse hover highlighting from a button

Tags: delphi, vcl

I've got a `TBitBtn` on a `TFrame` with a click event that causes the button's own frame to get unparented from its container (effectively removing it) and stored for later restoration:

```pascal
implementation
var
  StoredFrames: TStack<TFrame>;

procedure TCustomFrame.BitBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Some business logic
  Self.ActiveControl := nil;
  Self.Parent := nil;
  StoredFrames.Push(Self);
end;
```

Later, the frame is reparented into its container and thus redisplayed. However, the blue highlighting the button got from the mouse when it was clicked, before getting stored, remains on the button:

[image: TBitBtn with highlighting but no hovering]

After restoration, other controls can receive the same highlighting at the same time, but the button does not lose its highlighting until the frame is destroyed. **How can I manually reset or remove this button highlighting?**

Things I've tried:

- `Application.ProcessMessages` in the click handler
- Disabling the button on store, enabling on restore
- Various kinds of repainting/layout invalidation

Comment: How about posting a `WM_MOUSELEAVE` to the button before "un-parent" the frame?

Comment: ...actually post it after bringing the `Frame` back but first check if the cursor is above the Button or not. Now remember that this is a hack and there might exist a much purer way of doing this. Some might even ask why you are "un-parenting" in the first place and suggest you not do that.

Comment: @BlurrySterk Ultimately, posting `WM_MOUSELEAVE` right in the click handler for the button proved to be the best solution for this problem for me. The frame gets restored without any highlighting issues. If you would like to post this as an answer, I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per solution provided by @BlurrySterk in comments,

`BitBtn.Perform(WM_MOUSELEAVE, 0, 0);`

before unparenting the button's frame resets the button highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant solution, but it gets work done

```
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FRepaintTimer: TTimer;
    procedure OnRepaintTimer(Sender: TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFrame5.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not Assigned(FRepaintTimer) then
  begin
    FRepaintTimer := TTimer.Create(Self);
    FRepaintTimer.Interval := 50;
    FRepaintTimer.OnTimer := OnRepaintTimer;
  end;
  BitBtn1.Enabled := False;
  FRepaintTimer.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TFrame5.OnRepaintTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Self.ActiveControl := nil;
  Self.Parent := nil;
  BitBtn1.Enabled := True;
  FRepaintTimer.Enabled := False;
end;
```

Since timers are limited resource, maybe you could Hide/Show frames instead of making use of Parent and use OnHide/OnShow events from TFrame and Enable/Disable your buttons there.

Comment: In modern Delphi, you could replace the 1-shot `TTimer` with [`TThread.ForceQueue()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.ForceQueue) instead, which has an `ADelay` parameter, eg: `procedure TFrame5.RemoveFromParent; begin {Self.ActiveControl := nil;} Self.Parent := nil; BitBtn1.Enabled := True; end; procedure TFrame5.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject); begin BitBtn1.Enabled := False; TThread.ForceQueue(nil, RemoveFromParent, 50); end;`

Comment: Both of these solutions did in fact solve my issue, but ultimately were deemed too 'heavy' for solving a UI glitch. `TThread.ForceQueue()` is a new tool in my toolbox though!